# Using tiles with spring

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, tiles

while using tiles along with spring i m getting following error:

> java.net.UnknownHostException: tiles.apache.org

program runs fine when internet connection remains 'on' otherwise it shows above error.

can anyone provides me any hint???

Thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the problem was occurring due to very silly mistake that i missed the "space" between "Apache Software Foundation" in :

```
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.1//EN" "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd">
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case, this happens because of version mismatch of dtd. Here is the thing,

```
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.1//EN" "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd">
```

If we see the DOCTYPE there is a version "2.1" ("//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.1//EN") and the dtd should also be the same like "tiles-config_2_1.dtd". If the version is 3.1 ("//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.1//EN") and the dtd is "tiles-config_3_1.dtd".

I modified the version and its start working.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this issue by adding log4j-1.2.11.jar to web-inf/lib